# How to Update Text in File within Unix Shell Script

Tags: unix, shell

I'm creating a shell script that needs to update the sudoers file.  So basically I want to be able to append ":/usr/local/bin/" to the following text in /etc/sudoers:

secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

I need to use sudo in the command in order to gain the permissions to modify.  Any idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So many ways!

The old standby is sed: `sed 's/\(secure_path.*\)/\1:\/usr\/local\/bin/' /etc/sudoers`

Scripts in `vim` can do advanced things as well. Any process you would type into vim can be saved to a vim script and played back.

The newest tool that's really handy for this is [Augueas](http://augeas.net/). It's often used with Puppet is structured around editing files in a structured manner. Thus, it's aware of context and hierarchies within a text file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I get the following when I try that command:  sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @VinnyD Oops... I fixed up the escaped characters and quoting and tested it. Should work now.

Answer (score 1):

best thing to use is : sed - stream editor for filtering and transforming text